# How to display an Active Storage image variant with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, rails-activestorage

I can't display an image using Webpacker's `image_pack_tag`:

```
<%= image_pack_tag("http://localhost:3000" + Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(current_user.profil_picture.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed, only_path: true)) %>
```

I verified that the URL generated with

```
<%= "http://localhost:3000" + Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(current_user.profil_picture.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed, only_path: true)%>
```

works. I can access the variant but Webpacker keep raising this error:

```
Webpacker can't find http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9959728effdbb975d843d4f452319f6363c4ceac/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9VY21WemFYcGxYM1J2WDJ4cGJXbDBXd2RwTjJrMyIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoidmFyaWF0aW9uIn19--120e67a3ba1bc8800d715fbf351aea75a4993405/profile.jpg in /mnt/c/Users/lethu/Documents/apps/safe_date/public/packs/manifest.json.
```

Comment: please checkout https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/997#issuecomment-505743864

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm guessing this is because of `require.context('../images', true)` in `application.js`; Since user generated content can be stored anywhere (like S3, Azure etc) it must not be easy for webpack to resolve these assets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can't use image_pack_tag. Need to use insted image_tag